# SeekBar Volume hide slider on set max volume

Tags: android, xml, layout, seekbar

i have a seekbar defined in xml in this way:

```
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
<SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekVolume"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
</SeekBar>
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
```

and in activity i set seekbar to control volume in this way:

```
bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekVolume);
    am = (AudioManager)c.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    bar.setMax(maxVolume);
    bar.setProgress(curVolume);
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1*2, 0);
        }
    });
```

My problem borns when i put on seekbar max volume, so setting slider on the end of seekbar. Slider will be cut. I say better: a part of slider will be hidden from the end of layout. what can i do?

EDIT:

These are screenshots :

[image: this is slider in original dimension]
[image: And this is slider in seekbar max]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: of course! i'm edit post to add screenshots :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's imagine that your thumb image (what you drag) has a width of 10 dp.
Then you should set an offset and padding of half that width, like this:

```
android:thumbOffset="5dp" 
android:paddingRight="5dp" 
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try giving it some padding :

```
android:padding="5px"
```